# Scrape data from new site by following link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hyperlink, jupyter-notebook

I wonder if there is any example or suggested solution to use BeautifulSoup to scrape the data on a site that could be accessed by clicking on a hyperlink on the main webpage.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Can you inspect element to get the link and then scrape it? That could also be done programmatically.

Comment: I ran a loop and got all the hyperlinks on the main webpage, stored in a link, but I cannot pass them into the requests.get() function because it required me to pass in a string (I don't know why because the elements in my list are all strings)

Comment: The url isn't stored as a string? Just cast it using `str(thing_to_string)`